# Saving Files error

Tags: c#, file, save, append

need your eye on this.

```
void testSave()
    {
        fileName = curMonth.Text + curYear.Text + ".csv";
        if (!File.Exists(path+fileName))
        {
            File.Create(path + fileName);
        }
        else if (File.Exists(path + fileName))
        {
         try
           {
               lines = curDate.Text + "," + myDesc.Text + "," + myAmount.Text;
                File.AppendAllText(path + fileName, lines + Environment.NewLine);
                TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(path + fileName, true);
                tw.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }             
    }
```

The error come out as below:

> The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users...\File.csv' because it is being used by another process.

Any suggestion or solution i could refer? thanks

Comment: You can remove all the lines of code, except for `File.AppendAllText`. You don't need to check for file existence and create file manually. `File.AppendAllText` creates file if it does not exist. You also do nothing with your `TextWriter` - it simply opens a file and closes it without writing to it.

Comment: I want to check for the file existence because if that is new file i wanna to add some header before the data go in, if there any ways to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `File.Create(path + fileName);` is not closed so you cannot reopen.
- remove the `else` keyword if you want.

  ```
  void testSave()
  {
      fileName = curMonth.Text + curYear.Text + ".csv";
      if (!File.Exists(path+fileName))
      {
          try
          {
              File.Create(path + fileName).Close();
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
              MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
          }
      }

      try
      {
         lines = curDate.Text + "," + myDesc.Text + "," + myAmount.Text;
          File.AppendAllText(path + fileName, lines + Environment.NewLine);
          TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(path + fileName, true);
          tw.Close();
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
          MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Still the same problems happening...

Comment: do you have all the folders created?

Comment: ya, files will be create, but the data could not go in.

Comment: Hi, i found out the solution already. thanks ya.

This way to solved.
File.Create(path + fileName).Close();

Comment: Yes, it is exactly like that, i marked as answer. thanks you